# Error configuring SQL Reporting Services 2005 on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, iis-7, ssrs

I've installed SQL Server 2005 with **Reporting Services** on **Windows 7 Ultimate x64** and when I try to **configure** it when clicking on "**Windows Service Identity**" I get this error message:

> There was an error while switching panels. The most likely cause is an error retrieving WMI properties. The exception details are:
>
> InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
>   Parameter name: SelectedIndex

Here is a screenshot: [image: error message]

---

**EDIT:**

This problem disappeared after I installed SP3 for SQL Server. I have problems on the next panes though.

Now on the **Web Service Identity pane** the ASP.net service account textbox is empty, I select classic app pool for both dropdowns -> click apply and I get an error 
*"There was an error setting the identity for the web service. The previously set identity will be used."* and the details:

```
ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.WMIProviderException: The account name is not valid. Specify an account in the form domain\alias.
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.SetWebServiceIdentity(String applicationPool)
```

Comment: Details on the errors?

Comment: @Omu: are you running the config utility as an admin?

Comment: @MattB no I wasn't running it as an admin but I have my UAC turned off anyway, I tried now running it as an admin, and it's the same thing

Comment: @Jason Cumberland I've added the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I found the solution, all I had to do is:

on a clean Windows 7 Ultimate install,

- install IIS with all the required components for reporting services
- install sql server with reporting services (and don't start the configuration tool)
- install SP3 for sql server
- check for windows updates and install all of them than check again
- run the config tool as an administator and everything is configured (green) already

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a new application pool (I'm assuming you had it use an existing one but I could be wrong.) and set the user to one of the predefined ones, I use Network Service for just about everything.  If this is on a workstation that is not joined to a domain then the domain\username thing won't really work unless it's "workstationname\username" and you use a local account.  Network Service is the safest route here.  Also check to make sure that Network Service is set up to be in the local group named IIS_WPG on the workstation and that this user has full control on the report server and report manager directories.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like someone else is experiencing this problem; have a look at some possible solutions here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/7f57f1a0-3458-49b6-a0ff-820ba1385f6b